# How to get id of username from table 1 and insert that id to table 2

Tags: c#, sql, select, insert

I have 2 tables;

1. `Person` >> Id (PK)(Identity=yes), Username ,....
2. `Barcode`>> Id (FK), barcode ,....

I want to get Id from table 1 by session (session will be username) and insert that Id to table 2 . For example if `username==session` was true Id inserted, if not throw Exception. I want the Id of table 1 inserted to table2 relevant to same username which was in session. find below my work as of now;

---

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
        {
            string Message;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BCSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            con.Open();
            bool exists = false;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id from [Person] where username = @session", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@session", userInfo.Session);
                ?????
            }
            if (exists)
                Message = userInfo.Session + "The User Name has not been Registered...!";
            else
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Barcode (Id,Barcode,DateTime) values (@Id,@Barcode,@Datetime)", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", userInfo.Id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Barcode", userInfo.Barcode);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Datetime", userInfo.Datetime);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Vehicle", userInfo.Vehicle);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Message = userInfo.Barcode + "All of data Registered ";
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            return Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `Id` column is integer and your `SELECT` query return one cell, then you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get this value.

> Executes the query, and **returns the first column of the first row** in
>   the result set returned by the query.

```
int id;
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id from [Person] where username = @session", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@session", userInfo.Session);
    id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Then you can use this `id` value in your `INSERT` statement as you did in your example like;

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Barcode (Id,Barcode,DateTime) values (@Id,@Barcode,@Datetime)", con))
{
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
     ...
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Also I suggest to use `using` statement to dispose your `SqlConnection` also.

Comment: thanks for your comment how can i insert the same id (selected from table1) into table 2(barcode) by SqlCommand cmd ?

Comment: @aziz You just need to pass this value as a parameter in your `INSERT` statement. And are you sure you want to insert this value in your `Barcode` column? Shouldn't it `Id` column instead?

Comment: thank you ,, but when i use this code
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
the name ID does not exist in the current context

Comment: @aziz Because in my example, `id` variable defined in using scope. That's why you can't access it from another using scope (if it is not a child scope). I change my code to define `id` variable outside of using statement (On the top of inside `InsertUserDetails` method).

Answer (score 1):

[SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you need to get Id.

Remember you have to cast the retrieved value in your desired data type.

```
int iID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

I suggest following changes:

1. Add `using` block for SqlConnection as well.
2. Use single `SqlCommand`
3. Clear existing parameters before adding parameters for 2nd SqlCommand.

**Code**:

```
 public string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
    {
        string Message;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {   
             con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BCSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
             con.Open();      

             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id from [Person] where username = @session", con))
             {
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@session", userInfo.Session);
                  int iID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                  if(iID > 0) //check with reference to return ID
                  {
                     cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Barcode (Id,Barcode,DateTime) values (@Id,@Barcode,@Datetime)";
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", iID);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barcode", userInfo.Barcode);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datetime", userInfo.Datetime);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vehicle", userInfo.Vehicle);
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     Message = userInfo.Barcode + "All of data Registered ";                         
                  }                  
                  else
                     Message = userInfo.Session + "The User Name has not been Registered...!";
             }
        }
        return Message;
    }
```